# Align plots in Qt

Tags: python, qt, qwt

I want to be able to nicely align the description and the plot of following configuration:
[image]

I want to achieve that every plot has the same size, i.e. they end all on the same imaginary vertical line. The channel names should be aligned. Currently, I'm using a QGridLayout. The plots were created using Qwt.

Comment: If that's a grid layout you've got something weird going on. A 2x5 grid would line those all right up.

Comment: you're absolutely right, I was creating a new QGridLayout for every plot row. Sometimes it is that simple :P Thanks!